# Can someone please explain how this short fibonacci sequence code works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I understand recursion I just do not understand how this code works. I have tried to understand by printing the parameter `x` whenever the function is called.

```
def fib(x):
  print(x)
  if x == 0 or x == 1:
    return 1
  else: 
    return fib(x-1) +fib(x-2)

print(fib(4))
```

I get these outputs:

```
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
1
0
5
```

But this just doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is the difference equation

f(x)=f(x-1)+f(x-2), f(0)=f(1)=1

The if statement asks if your value is one of the 'default' values of the series, if it's not, then it must be calculated by recursion, which is done in the else statement.

As for why you obtain that confusing output is because the function fib() recursively calls itself, stacking every call.

In your example it goes like this

fib(4) prints **4**, then calls fib(3) and fib(2), it first attends fib(3)

fib(3) prints **3**, then calls fib(2) and fib(1), it first attends fib(2)

fib(2) prints **2**, then calls fib(1) and fib(0), it first attends fib(1)

fib(1) prints **1**, then returns 1

Now attends fib(0), which prints **0** and return 1

It goes up one line and attends fib(1) which prints **1** and return 1

Then it attends fib(2), prints **2** and calls fib(1) and fib(0), fib(1) prints **1** and returns 1, fib(0) prints **0** and return 0

And there you have your output. The last line is the answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is the execution order of the recursion, the blue boxes is each call of the function, and the red is the order.  Note how the red line passes through boxes in the order of your printout (starts top left and moves down left first).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should have an answer variable that equals number one + number two. Then, number one = number two and number two = answer.

Comment: what do you mean by an answer variable

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a depth counter would help explain:

```
 def fib(x, depth=0):
     print('\t' * depth + str(x))
     if x == 0 or x == 1:
             return 1
     else:
             return fib(x-1, depth+1) + fib(x-2, depth + 1)
```

output for `print(fib(4))`:

```
4
        3
                2
                        1
                        0
                1
        2
                1
                0
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're seeing is the internals to this recursion for this output and a demonstration of the programming language evaluating addition from left to right. You can think about this Fibionacci algorithm like this for `fib(4)` if we look at each output:

```
4  - Call to fib(4)
3  - fib(4)'s call to fib(4-1)
2  - fib(4-1)'s call to fib(4-1-1)
1  - fib(4-1-1)'s call to fib(4-1-1-1): this returns a value of 1 because x = 1
0  - fib(4-1-1)'s call to fib(4-1-1-2): this returns 1 because x = 0; fib(4-1-1) returns 2 because the two 1s are added together
1  - fib(4-1)'s call to fib(4-1-2): this returns a value of 1 because x = 1; the 1 from this is added to the 2 from fib(4-1-1) to make the result for fib(4-1)
2  - fib(4)'s call to fib(4-2)
1  - fib(4-2)'s call to fib(4-2-1): this returns 1 because x = 1
0  - fib(4-2)'s call to fib(4-2-2): this returns 1 because x = 0; fib(4-2) returns 1+1 = 2; fib(4) returns 5 because fib(4-1) returned 3 and fib(4-2) returned 2
5  - Final result
```

Looking at the operations, whenever we get to the `return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)` instruction, every time `fib(x-1)` is performed first because of order of operations being from left to right like how we read.

On the computer level, it expands the operations something like this with each line being iteratively deeper:

```
fib(4)
fib(4-1) + fib(4-2)
(fib(3-1) + fib(3-2)) + fib(4-2)
((fib(2-1) + fib(2-2)) + fib(3-2)) + fib(4-2)
((fib(1) + fib(0)) + fib(3-2)) + fib(4-2)
((1+1) + fib(3-2)) + fib(4-2)
(2 + fib(1)) + fib(4-2)
(2+1) + fib(4-2)
3 + fib(2)
3 + (fib(2-1) + fib(2-2))
3 + (fib(1) + fib(0))
3 + (1 + 1)
3 + 2
5
```

I've compacted a few parts for space concerns, but it should get the point across hopefully.